# A non-zero element in a prime ideal has a prime factor

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Stuck in reading a proof of a random theorem:

> For a PID $R$ it is assumed that for an $f \neq 0$ in a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset R[X]$ there is a prime element $f'$ dividing $f$.

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $R$ is a PID, hence a UFD, by Gauss'
 lemma $R[X]$ is also a UFD. Since $0\neq f\in\mathfrak{p}$, $f$ is not a unit, so its factorization into a unit and irreducibles must actually contain some irreducibles, which are the same as primes since we're in a UFD.